# Как загрузить html страницы в джанго-админ?

Tags: python, django, база-данных, алгоритм

Подскажите пожалуйста. У меня есть html страница. Как через models.py я могу в базу данных в Django, добавить эту страничку?

Я создал приложение в джанго, под названием apps. В этом приложение есть model.py.Как мне создать модель и создать в ней переменную, которая бы отвечала за загрузку и хранение файла в джанго админ?

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Я создал приложение в джанго, под названием apps. В этом приложение есть model.py.Как мне создать модель и создать в ней переменную, которая бы отвечала за загрузку и хранение файла в джанго админ?

Comment: Ну сделайте самый обычный TextField и просто выводите его содержимое в каком-нибудь шаблоне, или даже сразу заворачивайте в HttpResponse во вьюхе. Не совсем понятно в чём у вас проблема